# store values from form to grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have create a add record form in extjs which stores user entered data into grid.

Well , if found following method to get form values from formPanel

```
var formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({...});
var form = formPanel.getForm();
var firstName = form.findField('firstname').getValue();
```

but i want to covert all the user input value into JSON and want to store into Grid panel and want to send it to the server also. but using findField i have to manually create the array and then need to encode it into JSON , so is there any alternate way to directly read values from form and convert it into JSON and store it into Grid Panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "want to store in the GridPanel" would you be updating an existing record in the Grid's store or would you be inserting a new one or both? (depending on whether its add or update probably?)

For such situations, BasicForm (var form in your snippet above) provides `updateRecord( Record record )` method.

So your steps would be -

```
var record = Record.create(...) // in case of insert
```

OR

```
var record = //obtain record from grid.getStore() in case of update
```

Then,

```
formPanel.getForm().updateRecord(record); //update the passed record with values from the form
```

Followed by committing the record back to the store-

```
grid.getStore().add(record); //in case of insert
grid.getStore().commitChanges(); //incase of update
```

Reference - [Ext.form.BasicForm](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.BasicForm) , [Ext.data.Record](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.Record)

Define your record type -

```
MyRecordType = Ext.data.Record.create(['id', 'field1', 'field2']);

var myrec = new MyrecordType();
```

Now pass myrec to updateRecord as mentioned above.

Comment: Yes i want to insert the new one and want to update the existing one also.

Comment: How do i convert form fields into Record , as using getvalues i can have array of fields but how can i convert it into Records

Comment: Like I mentioned above, dont use get getValues. Instead use updateRecord. When you use updateRecord, ExtJS does its magic to get the fields and updates the record (that you have passed in updateRecord) for you.

Comment: But what about new record that i need to insert a fresh one for that i need to gather values from form right , so i was asking about that

Comment: you create an empty record from your field definitions and pass it to updateRecord